# Disable button once clicked or close the modal immediately

Tags: jquery

```
 $('button#rejectWithdraw').click(function(e) {

  $.ajax({
          url: $('#rejectUrl').val(),
          type: "POST",
          data: {data:text},
          success: function (data) {
              $('#modelContent').modal('toggle');
          },
          error: function (err) {
             // alert("Something went wrong"+err);
          }
      });

});
```

The modal closes only after success. I need it closes immediately after submit or the button should be disabled after once clicked.

How to do this?

Comment: If you want to close the modal immediately, move the `.modal('toggle')` line to within the `click` event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting property 'disabled' to true:

```
$('button#rejectWithdraw').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: It works on microsoft edge. but not in chrome. What to do?

Comment: If it works on edge, it surely does work in Chrome. Works for me on Chrome. Try Ctrl+F5 to perform a hard-refresh of content.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add disabled propery like

```
$('button#rejectWithdraw').click(function(e) {
  $('button#rejectWithdraw').prop('disabled', true);
  $.ajax({
          url: $('#rejectUrl').val(),
          type: "POST",
          data: {data:text},
          success: function (data) {
              $('#modelContent').modal('toggle');
          },
          error: function (err) {
             // alert("Something went wrong"+err);
          }
      });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The modal closes after success because the code closing the modal

`$('#modelContent').modal('toggle');`

is in success handler. If you want it to be executed imidiately after submit you can just place it right after your $.ajax call.

```
$('button#rejectWithdraw').click(function(e) {

  $.ajax({
      url: $('#rejectUrl').val(),
      type: "POST",
      data: {data:text},
      success: function (data) {
         // code placed here is executed only on successfull POST
      },
      error: function (err) {
         // alert("Something went wrong"+err);
      }
  });

  $('#modelContent').modal('toggle');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.one()` of JQuery like this to make the button click only once:

```
$( "button#rejectWithdraw" ).one( "click", function(e) {
  $.ajax({
          url: $('#rejectUrl').val(),
          type: "POST",
          data: {data:text},
          success: function (data) {
              $('#modelContent').modal('toggle');
          },
          error: function (err) {
             // alert("Something went wrong"+err);
          }
      });

 });
```

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.